# Facing problem with signature parameter using Java in Android App

Tags: java, android, postman, retrofit

I am unable to do this in my android app using java language. I am using the retrofit library for this but the problem is the signature. unable to generate proper signature which gives me an error. It is working in POSTMAN and getting proper responses. Help me to convert this in JAVA.

Documentation of API - https://docs.wazirx.com/#fund-details-user_data

POSTMAN PRE-REQUEST SCRIPT
MAIN PARAMS --> BASE_URL, API_KEY, SECRET_KEY, SIGNATURE & TIMESTAMP in miliseconds.

```
    var navigator = {}; //fake a navigator object for the lib
    var window = {}; //fake a window object for the lib
    const privateKey = pm.environment.get("rsa_private_key");
    
    const secretKey = pm.environment.get("secret_key");
    
    // Set Current Time
    var time = new Date().getTime()
    postman.setEnvironmentVariable("current_time", time)
    
    query_a = pm.request.url.query.toObject(true)
    
    // Generate Request Payload
    let query_string_array = []
    Object.keys(query_a).forEach(function(key) {
        if (key == 'signature') { return }
        if (key == 'timestamp') {
            query_string_array.push(key + "=" + time)
        }
        else if (typeof query_a[key] == "string") {
            query_string_array.push(key + "=" + query_a[key])
        } else {
            query_a[key].forEach(function(value){
                query_string_array.push(key + "=" + value)
            })
        }
    })
    
    const payload = query_string_array.join("&")
    console.log("Request Payload = ", payload)
    
    if(secretKey) {
        const signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(payload, secretKey) + ''
        pm.environment.set("signature", signature)
        console.log("Signature = "+signature);
    } else {
        // Download RSA Library
        pm.sendRequest(pm.environment.get("rsa_library_js"), function (err, res) {
    
            if (err){
                console.log("Error: " + err);
            }
            else {
                // Compile & Run RSA Library
                eval(res.text())();
    
                // Sign Payload
                var signatureLib = new KJUR.crypto.Signature({"alg": "SHA256withRSA"});
                signatureLib.init(privateKey);
                signatureLib.updateString(payload);
                var signatureHash = hex2b64(signatureLib.sign());
                console.log("Signature = ", signatureHash)
    
                // Assign Values
                pm.environment.set("signature", encodeURIComponent(signatureHash, "UTF-8"))
            }
        })
    }


Java Code: 

//REQUEST CLASS START -->

public class Request {
String baseUrl;
    String apiKey="1***uR7";
    String apiSecret="b1**qVmh";
    Signature sign = new Signature();

    public Request(String baseUrl, String apiKey, String apiSecret) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
        this.apiSecret = apiSecret;
    }

    private void printResponse(HttpURLConnection con) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        System.out.println(response.toString());
    }

    private void printError(HttpURLConnection con) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getErrorStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        System.out.println(response.toString());
    }

    private String getTimeStamp() {
        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return "timestamp=" + timestamp;
    }

    //concatenate query parameters
    private String joinQueryParameters(HashMap<String,String> parameters) {
        String urlPath = "";
        boolean isFirst = true;

        for (Map.Entry mapElement : parameters.entrySet()) {
            if (isFirst) {
                isFirst = false;
                urlPath += mapElement.getKey() + "=" + mapElement.getValue();
            } else {
                urlPath += "&" + mapElement.getKey() + "=" + mapElement.getValue();
            }
        }
        return urlPath;
    }

    private void send(URL obj, String httpMethod) throws Exception {
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        if (httpMethod != null) {
            con.setRequestMethod(httpMethod);
        }
        //add API_KEY to header content
        con.setRequestProperty("X-API-KEY", apiKey);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
            printResponse(con);
        } else {
            printError(con);
        }

    }

    public void sendPublicRequest(HashMap<String,String> parameters, String urlPath) throws Exception {
        String queryPath = joinQueryParameters(parameters);
        URL obj = new URL(baseUrl + urlPath + "?" + queryPath);
        System.out.println("url:" + obj.toString());

        send(obj, null);
    }

    public void sendSignedRequest(HashMap<String,String> parameters, String urlPath, String httpMethod) throws Exception {
        String queryPath = "";
        String signature = "";

        if (!parameters.isEmpty()) {
            queryPath += joinQueryParameters(parameters) + "&" + getTimeStamp();
        } else {
            queryPath += getTimeStamp();
        }
        try {
            signature = sign.getSignature(queryPath, apiSecret);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Please Ensure Your Secret Key Is Set Up Correctly! " + e);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        queryPath += "&signature=" + signature;

        URL obj = new URL(baseUrl + urlPath + "?" + queryPath);
        System.out.println("url:" + obj.toString());

        send(obj, httpMethod);
    }
}

//REQUEST CLASS END -->

//SPOT CLASS START -->
public class Spot {
    private static final String API_KEY = System.getenv("1***57");
    private static final String API_SECRET = System.getenv("b****n8");
    HashMap<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String,String>();
    Request httpRequest;

    public Spot() {
        String baseUrl = "https://api.wazirx.com";
        httpRequest = new Request(baseUrl, API_KEY, API_SECRET);
    }
    public void account() throws Exception {
        httpRequest.sendSignedRequest(parameters, "/sapi/v1/funds", "GET");

    }
}
//SPOT CLASS END-->

//SIGNATURE CLASS START-->

public class Signature {
    final String HMAC_SHA256 = "HmacSHA256";

    //convert byte array to hex string
    private String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        final char[] hexArray = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for (int j = 0, v; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }

    public String getSignature(String data, String key) {
        byte[] hmacSha256 = null;
        try {
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), HMAC_SHA256);
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA256);
            mac.init(secretKeySpec);
            hmacSha256 = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to calculate hmac-sha256", e);
        }
        return bytesToHex(hmacSha256);
    }
}
//SIGNATURE CLASS END-->
```

Comment: Kindly note that Stackoverflow is not a free code converting service. Please show us the Java code you have written so far and you are struggling with. Please add some sampledata as well (keys, plaintext, signature), thanks.

Comment: @MichaelFehr I added my java code.